# Best way to parse canbus data in arduino?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, arduino

I have esp32 with arduino ide connected to canbus. Im getting flow of data from rx_frame.data.u8[] which has 8 bytes eg. [FF, FF, FF, 61, 3F, FF, FF, FF];

I need take rx_frame.data.u8[3] and rx_frame.data.u8[4] eg. 61 and 3F, get them to intel byte order(reverse byte order?) eg. 3F61 and convert to DEC. It should return 16255.

Problem: I cant get rx_frame.data.u8[] to intel byte order and then convert to DEC. Ive tried couple things, I was able to make intel byte order with String engspd1 = String(rx_frame.data.u8[4], HEX) + String(rx_frame.data.u8[3], HEX); but now I have problem to convert String engspd1 to DEC.
Also I will be parsing lots of data, so Im not sure which way is best to parse that kind of data flow.

P.S. sorry if I made some mistakes in my question by naming stuff differently. Im just starting with C, C++ and arduino ide.

```
#include <CAN_config.h>


CAN_device_t CAN_cfg;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("iotsharing.com CAN demo");
    CAN_cfg.speed=CAN_SPEED_250KBPS;
    CAN_cfg.tx_pin_id = GPIO_NUM_5;
    CAN_cfg.rx_pin_id = GPIO_NUM_4;
    CAN_cfg.rx_queue = xQueueCreate(10,sizeof(CAN_frame_t));
    //start CAN Module
    ESP32Can.CANInit();
}

void loop() {
    CAN_frame_t rx_frame;
    //receive next CAN frame from queue
    if(xQueueReceive(CAN_cfg.rx_queue,&rx_frame, 3*portTICK_PERIOD_MS)==pdTRUE){

      //do stuff!

        if(rx_frame.MsgID == 217056256) {
        String engspd1 = String(rx_frame.data.u8[4], HEX) + String(rx_frame.data.u8[3], HEX);
        int engspd2 = engspd1.toInt(); // throws error of course
        Serial.println(engspd1);
        Serial.println(engspd2);
      }
```

Comment: There's no need to make things so complicated. Just bitshift the upper byte left by 8 after casting to a larger type, then bitwise or it with the lower byte.

Comment: It sounds like something I need, by any chance you have time to show sample code?

Comment: I'd do something like `unsigned engspd2 = (unsigned) rx_frame.data.u8[4] << 8 | rx_frame.data.u8[3];`.

Comment: Bitshift works great and I think its not using much resources, thank you very much for great sample!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are accessing bytes 5 and 4, not 3 and 4. Is that your problem? C arrays are zero indexed so 3 and 4 are the locations of the bytes you are wanting.

Comment: Sorry my mistake in question. But its not the problem.

Comment: Problem is that I cant effectively parse 2 bytes from array.
first I have change order of byte[3] byte[4] to byte[4] byte[3].
second I need get DEC value of byte[4] byte[3]

Comment: Did you try what @Thomas Jager suggested? That should work assuming that engspd2 is zero when it starts (because the bitwise OR) and is 16 bits long.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add your byte to get the result you want. (Your array is not in hex since this is only a representation the controller knows nothing about.

```
int engspd2 = rx_frame.data.u8[4] << 8 + rx_frame.data.u8[3];
```